# Form Fields: Name and Phone Not Passed Along with Request in Paystack

Tags: laravel

I am trying to implement Paystack in Laravel; I'm using their suggested documentation for Laravel. The issue is that the amount and email get passed onto the Paystack database, but the customer's name and phone details aren't. How do I get it to be passed along to Paystack?

I have configured the checkout process as mentioned in the documentation based on https://github.com/unicodeveloper/laravel-paystack. I'm using Windows 10 and running Laravel 5.6 and PHP 7.3.

```php
<form class="needs-validation" action="{{ route('pay') }}" method="POST">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="first_name">First name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name"
                   placeholder="first name" value="" name="first_name" required="">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
            <label for="last_name">Last name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name"
                   placeholder="last Name" name="last_name" value="" required="">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label for="email">Email <span class=" text-danger"> * </span>
        </label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email"
               placeholder="you@example.com" required>
    </div>
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <hr class="mb-4">
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" type="submit"
            value="Pay Now!">
        <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg"></i> Complete Payment!
    </button>
</form>
```

I expected that after the payment is complete, the customer data should contain the customer email, and name. But it returns only the email in the customer array.

Comment: I just did a dd($response) and the name and email were actually submitted from the form but only the email got to the paystack database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to implement it yourself, before the pay button try to have a form like this

```
<form action="/myform" method="post">
<input type="text" name="fullname">
<input type="number" name="phone_number">
<button>submit</button>
</form>

Route::post('/myform','controllerhere@form1')->name('name');
Route::get('/pay','controller@function')->name('pay');
Route::post('/pay','controller@function')->name('pay');
```

then your controller to look like this

```
public function form1(Request $request){
$request->validate([....]);
save the form and return redirect to your payment form like this
..
return redirect('/pay');
}
```

then payments can be made, please the above codes are just samples to help

Comment: The @function for the '/pay' route are the ones from the package right?

Comment: Yes, the one for paystack payment

Comment: Thanks A lot Mr Emeka

Comment: The return redirect line does not pass along the request. The parameter is null.

Comment: Done the steps helped a lot

Comment: if the steps shown above was helpful and you will not like any further answers then mark the answer to show that you have gotten the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively if you check the https://github.com/unicodeveloper/laravel-paystack package, there is a commented section in the **paystack.php**; this contains a sample of how to add custom_fields to the metadata.

```
`<input type="hidden" name="metadata" value="{{ json_encode($array) }}" >`
```

`$array = [ 'custom_fields' => [
             ['display_name' => "Cart Id", "variable_name" => "cart_id", "value" => "2"],
             ['display_name' => "Sex", "variable_name" => "sex", "value" => "female"],
                               ]
             ]`

Edit this to add name of the customer and amount then if you dd($paymentdatails) you will see the details in metadata.